# How can I bypass ESLint calling the Geolocation interface undefined in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, geolocation, eslint

I am utilizing the Geolocation API to place a marker on a map, but ESLint is complaining that GeolocationPosition is undefined. Nevertheless, the code runs and gives me the expected result, but I want to clean my code for warnings. I am new to typescript and ESlint, so I am unsure where to go from here. Any suggestions? Code and image of warning follows.

[image]

```
import { Map } from 'leaflet';
import { iconLocation, setMarker } from './leafletMarker';

export function getUserPosition(callback : (position : GeolocationPosition) => void) {
    function success(position : GeolocationPosition) {
        callback(position);
    }
    function error() {
        console.log('Unable to retrieve your location'); // change to alerts when Alert component is ready
    }
    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        console.log('Geolocation is not supported by your browser'); // change to alerts when Alert component is ready
    } else {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, { enableHighAccuracy: true });
    }
}

export function handleMyPosition(map: Map) {
    getUserPosition((userPosition: GeolocationPosition) => {
        if (map) {
            const { latitude, longitude } = userPosition.coords;
            setMarker(map, latitude, longitude, { icon: iconLocation });
            map?.setView([latitude, longitude], 9);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not _configure_ it, rather than bypassing it? See e.g. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals.

Comment: If you mean change the config so that eslint no longer checks undefined, that is not ideal. Perhaps I am using geolocation the wrong way, and if so do you know how I could fix it?

Comment: I mean change the config so that ESLint knows that `GeolocationPosition` _will_ be defined. Actually it looks like you need to configure it more generally to know about TypeScript.

Comment: I see. my eslint file is configured to utilize typescript, and was working fine until this issue. I read the docs you linked, but am still unsure how to do what you are suggesting.

Comment: I dont think @typescript-eslint/no-undef is a thing. Earlier, I changed the no-unused-vars rule to the typescript version, and couldn't find a similar one for undef. While typing this out, however, I realized that the undef rule basically wants to do what typescript already does, so I removed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Don't use no-undef in TypeScript projects](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/FAQ.md#i-get-errors-from-the-no-undef-rule-about-global-variables-not-being-defined-even-though-there-are-no-typescript-errors). Just disable the rule in your config, TypeScript does the same but better.

Comment: Yes, as you see in my comment above I just realized this prior to this post. Nevertheless, this is the answer - Thank you.